# Error with publishing my game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have created simple game with integration of flare3D which accessing gpu accelerationi have uploaded my files to player io server but when i load my index .html it just started and never load contents ..but if i try to run from local machine it loads up all the game file and work perfect . Any help please

Comment: First, perform your usual debug via a textfield and any error handler dumping info there.

Comment: does it say 'movie not loaded' when you right-click the flashplayer? Could be the paths to include swf are wrong. Also, check for uppercase/lowercase. Unix servers are case sensitive so Main.swf is not the same as main.swf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flare3D just as any of the Stage3D engines out there uses GPU to render its content. When publishing to the web you must change the `wmode` property of the embedded SWF to `direct`. This is why it works when you launch the SWF directly in Flash Player and not on the page.

Answer (score 0):

First, try give full paths to all loaders instead relative paths.

Second, you can connect you debugger as "debug external application" and what is happen.

Comment: And in Flare3D's loaders you can give loaded ByteArray (or embedded Class) instead url/uri.

Comment: And are you using swfObject.js?